# Why does my program crash when the "Save As" dialog box is exited?

Tags: vb.net

Every time I enter the "Save As" dialog box the program crashes if the file is not saved, however it works fine when the file is saved. I understand why its happening (**because there is an invalid file name when the user exits the dialog box**) but I don't know how to fix it.

**The specific problem is that the program crashes when the user exits the dialog box without saving the file.**

Thanks for the help in advance :)

[This is the text to be saved in a txt. file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOQPw.jpg)

[This is the error I recieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOW1p.jpg)

```
Private Sub btnSaveDetails_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveDetails.Click
    Dim ni As IO.StreamWriter
    Dim itms() As String = {ListBox.Items.ToString}
    Dim save As New SaveFileDialog
    Dim it As Integer
    save.Filter = "*.txt|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*" 
    save.CheckPathExists = True 
    save.ShowDialog(Me)
    ni = New IO.StreamWriter(save.FileName)
    For it = 0 To ListBox.Items.Count - 1
        ni.WriteLine(ListBox.Items.Item(it))
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("File Saved!")
    ni.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce **it in the question itself**

Comment: @Plutonix Desired behaviour would be for the program not to crash. The specific problem is that the program crashes when the dialog box is exited, and he shortest code is the code provided which cant be downsized, but ill remember that for next time.

Comment: ...you missed the part about the specific error **in the question itself**.  Links to pictures of error messages are not helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846956/how-to-exit-a-sub-if-a-dialog-is-closed?rq=1

Comment: If they canceled the dialog, you have to cancel the save. That's all there is to it. Obviously that's what the user wants, they chose *not* to save! I'm having trouble understanding what the question is here.

Comment: @CodyGray I understand that the user doesn't want to save it but when they exit the dialog box the program crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to method `ShowDialog` returns a value of type `DialogResult`.  You need to check if this value is equal to `DialogResult.OK`, and only attempt to write your file if it is. If it is not, you should skip the file IO.

Something like this (note the use of `Using` blocks to automatically dispose objects that require it):

```
Private Sub btnSaveDetails_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveDetails.Click
    Dim itms() As String = {ListBox.Items.ToString}
    Using save As New SaveFileDialog
        save.Filter = "*.txt|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*" 
        save.CheckPathExists = True 
        If save.ShowDialog(Me) == DialogResult.OK Then
            Using ni As New IO.StreamWriter(save.FileName)
                Dim it As Integer
                For it = 0 To ListBox.Items.Count - 1
                    ni.WriteLine(ListBox.Items.Item(it))
                Next
            End Using
            MessageBox.Show("File Saved!")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Save Aborted!")
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: The second = sign in line 6 still crashes the program. Once I had removed that = sign the program worked perfectly. Thanks!